# Linq select all items where in list with groupby

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following data as a list:

```
raceId   data   position
1        A      0
1        B      0
1        F      1 
1        J      0
2        A      2
2        F      1
3        A      0
3        J      2
3        M      1
3        V      3
```

I need to get the total (count) of races where there are ALL matching letters with the same raceid.

I.E a search on 'A' and 'J' = 2 (race's 1 and 3)

In addition I need to get the position data for each.

```
raceId   data   position
1        A      0
1        J      0
3        A      0
3        J      2
```

So far I have the following code.

```
 var dataValues = new string[] { 'A', 'J' };

 var races = raceData
    .GroupBy( ac => ac.raceId )
    .Select( grp => grp.First() )
    .Where( t =>
        dataValues
        .All( s =>
            dataValues
            .Contains( t.data )
        )
    );

 var racecount = races.count()
```

The issue is that this returns all `raceId` values where there is either letter in the data.

Comment: You don't need `Group`. Just `raceValues.Where(record => dataValues.Contains(record.data));`

Comment: How about posting `raceData` so that we don't have to create your sample environment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
var results = raceData.GroupBy(rd => rd.raceId)
   .Where(g => dataValues.All(dv => g.Select(g2 => g2.data).Contains(dv)));

int raceCount = results.Count();

var results2 = results
    .SelectMany(g => g)
    .Where(rd => dataValues.Contains(rd.data));
```

`raceCount` will give you 2 and `results2` will give you the 4 records you're expecting.

It works for me with your provided data anyway!

Comment: Downvoter care to explain? You're not helping the site if you don't explain why you think it's a poor answer.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but you don't have a definition for result to get raceCount.

Comment: I am not downvoter: but _In addition I need to get the position data for each._ this make question unclear. Seems like OP want races with data in `dataValues`. And count is amount of races after filtering

Comment: @NetMage Thank you, it was a copy/paste error. Should have been `results`.

Comment: @Fabio The position data is part of the records that result from `results2`. I guess I could just throw on a `Select(rd => rd.position)`? I don't follow you on your comment about the count. The number of races is originally 3, and my filtering returns 2 in accordance with the OP's requirements so far as I can tell.

Comment: I think your answer might be (a little) better if you did `var results2 = results.SelectMany(g => g.Where(r => dataVals.Contains(r.data)));`

Comment: @itsme86, sorry, my comment was wrong, your decision is correct. Return only races which have all items(of `data`) from `dataValue`. And provide full information of races.

Comment: Thats great thanks. Sorry for the delay in accepting the answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
var groupedRaces = from r in raceData 
    group r by r.raceId into gp 
    select new { raceId = gp.Key, Datas = gp.Select(g => g.data).ToArray() };

var raceIds = from r in groupedRaces 
    where dataVals.All(mv => r.Datas.Contains(mv))
    select r.raceId;

var races = from r in raceData
    where raceIds.Contains(r.raceId) && dataVals.Contains(r.data)
    select r;
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this,

```
list.GroupBy(t => t.raceID).SelectMany(k => k).Where(x => dataValues.Contains(x.data))
.Select(f=> new { f.data ,f.position,f.raceID}).ToList();
```

**Result**,

[image]

Hope helps,

Comment: Totaly input binded answer.

Comment: @eocron06 Read the question please. There is list of item, and he explained that _a search on 'A' and 'J' = 2 (race's 1 and 3)_ and also there is a string array for comparision. How can it be dynamic please explain or add an answer.

Comment: I think OP asked about general principle of doing it. If you think this input is constant, then something totaly wrong and you can just yield final answer.

Comment: @eocron06 OP clearly specified his conditions, how can it be general? He has an array of searching strings?

Comment: @Berkay Not downvoter, but probably for the same reason as the first. Your query relies on already determining which races meet the criteria. You shouldn't have to already know that races 1 and 3 qualify.